# RegEx fo replacing numbers in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

This is my string:

```
" "hello": 0, "zulu": 1,234, "Bravo": 987.456 "
```

I wish to replace any number (integer or real with a thousand's separator or not) in the string using regex and get this new string:

```
 "hello": "0", "zulu": "1,234", "Bravo": "987.456" "
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Asking for a regex is the same thing as asking for code. The StackOverflow community prefers that you research your problem, try a solution, and ask us when you encounter problems in your own solution.

Comment: your string it is not a Json Format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the numbers using this regex,

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*
```

Here, `\d+` captures a number having one or more digits and `(?:[,.]\d+)*` optionally captures more digits that are either comma or dot separated, and replace them with `"$0"` where `$0` represents whole match.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5yL1UC/1)**

Java code demo,

```
String s = "\" \"hello\": 0, \"zulu\": 1,234, \"Bravo\": 987.456 \"";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\d+(?:[,.]\\d+)*", "\"$0\""));
```

Prints,

```
" "hello": "0", "zulu": "1,234", "Bravo": "987.456" "
```

Also, your expected result seems to be missing the doublequote and space that you have in the start of input string and that should most likely be a typo.